# Orion not using FIWARE Service on Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, fiware-orion

I'm having a weird issue using Orion on Kubernetes. When using Orion 2.5 (also happens with 3.6) and MongoDB 4.4 on Docker-Compose, everything works as expected, I'm able to create and retrieve entities in Orion and they are created properly in databases with the proper name (if fiware-service is service, the database is orion-service).

However, using the same in Kubernetes, with the same commands in Orion and everything configured the same way, it ignores the service. I can see in the logs that Orion receives the service and service-path

```
time=2022-04-29T12:20:44.125Z | lvl=INFO | corr=cac0239e-c7b6-11ec-abd6-f6ce73396b62 | trans=1651234819-423-00000000003 | from=127.0.0.1 | srv=acc1234121 | subsrv=/asd | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: POST /v2/entities, request payload (288 bytes)
```

However, it creates the entity in the orion database (without using the -service, which would be orion-acc1234121 in this case).

Could you provide some insights on how to debug the issue and if there is some configuration I'm missing?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:** We finally figured out the issue. In the chart, we were not setting properly the multiservice option, so it was set to false. The point is we are not able to see it neither in the command executed (output of ps command) nor in the environment variables. Anyway, thank you very much for your help, we can mark this as closed and solved.

Comment: Orion 2.5.0 is very old (October 2020). I'd suggest to upgrade to the newest one (3.6.0 at the moment of writing this) and re-evaluate if the problem stills appending.

Comment: Information about CLI parameters and environment variables used when running Orion can help to diagnose the problem (I.E -multiservice CLI command)

Comment: I agree with @mapedraza. Please edit your question post to include the CLI used by Orion (`ps -ax | grep contextBroker` uses to provide that information).

Comment: Good morning @mapedraza @fgalan, que have been performing some test as we found out some interesting things, but we are not able to figure out why it doesn't work.

- Tested with both, 2.5.0 and 3.6.0, and both of them produce the same behaviour.
- Ps command provides the following output

`bash-4.4$ ps xua | grep contextBroker
nobody       1  0.0  0.1 544432 18376 ?        Ssl  Apr29   0:01 contextBroker -fg -dbhost mongo-standalone-mongodb -logLevel DEBUG -t 255`

Comment: - We moved to the [official helm chart] (https://github.com/FIWARE/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/orion) (we had a custom one) and it works, at least with one replica of the Mongo. I uploaded out [custom helm chart](https://github.com/carloscorrales/orion-helmchart) to GitHub:

The output using the custom helmchart posted is like this

`nobody         1  0.0  0.0 2261408 12224 ?       Ssl  Apr06   9:57 contextBroker -fg -port 1026 -notificationMode transient -httpTimeout 30000 -logLevel INFO -dbhost mongodb-headless -rplSet rs0 -dbTimeout 10000 -corsOrigin __ALL -reqMutexPolicy none`

Comment: Comparing both CLIs, I'd say that `-rplSet rs0` is doing the trick... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: We finally figured out the issue. In the chart, we were not setting properly the multiservice option, so it was set to false. The point is we are not able to see it neither in the command executed (output of ps command) nor in the environment variables. Anyway, thank you very much for your help, we can mark this as closed and solved.

Comment: I'd suggest to self-answer your question with a post based in the previous comment. It is better if the solution is in the proper answer post that hidden in a comment to the question post ;)